# How to transform Include attribute value of PackageReference property in .csproj using Package.props file?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, csproj, dotnetcorecli

In my solution I'm using `Package.props` file for settings versions for referenced packages.

For instance if I want to add a nuget package `Microsoft.Cool.Package` to one of my solution's projects, I just put in corresponding `.csproj` file a line:

```
<PackageReference Include="My.Cool.Package" />
```

And also add another one to `Package.props`:

```
<PackageReference Update="My.Cool.Package" Version="1.0.1" />
```

For local development I sometimes want to replace nuget package reference in all projects, like I want: `<PackageReference Include="My.Cool.Package" />` to become `<PackageReference Include="../../My.Cool.Package.csproj" />`.

How can I achieve that just by making corresponding change in `Package.props` file, which will override all non local package includes.

Comment: You mean `Directory.Packages.props`, right? You cannot 'transform' an include, but you can remove (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#BKMK_RemoveAttribute) an item first then include it again

Comment: Thanks for your comment, just wanted to clarify how can I remove and include it only if it existed in .csproj before?

Comment: Right that's a fair question; I'll add an answer

Answer (score 4):

If your .csproj has

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="My.Cool.Package"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

then in Directory.Packages.props you can figure that out using

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <HasCoolPackage>@(PackageReference->AnyHaveMetadataValue("Identity", "My.Cool.Package"))</HasCoolPackage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and based on that remove it and something else instead:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="../My.Cool.Package.csproj" Condition="$(HasCoolPackage) == True"/>
  <PackageReference Remove="My.Cool.Package" Condition="$(HasCoolPackage) == True"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Note: due to msbuild evaluation order the lines must be in the order shown otherwise msbuild would first remove the package, then evaluate the property again and it would be false at that point.